# Android XML Dynamically Set Margin Heights

Tags: android, android-layout

In android, I need to have layout sizes dependent on variables in the ViewModel. For example:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/amount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Example"
                android:layout_marginTop="@{viewModel.interfaceEnable ? 0dp : 10dp}"
                />
```

Based on the value in `viewModel.interfaceEnable`, its either going to be 0dp or 10dp. But the error I am getting is this:

```
Syntax error: extraneous input 'p' expecting {'.', '::', '[', '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '<<', '>>>', '>>', '<=', '>=', '>', '<', 'instanceof', '==', '!=', '&', '^', '|', '&&', '||', '?', ':', '??'}
```

How can I set dp or any value through that kind of check?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
android:layout_marginTop="@{viewModel.interfaceEnable ? @dimen/no_margin : @dimen/margin_normal}"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure. In your dimen.xml file, between <resources> </resources> tag, add:

`code`<dimen name="no_margin">0</dimen>
<dimen name="margin_normal">10</dimen>

Comment: But why would `@dimen/no_margin : @dimen/margin_normal` work and `0dp : 10dp` not?

Comment: That's because databinding will consider it as a reference and will know what to do with it, in this case, pick its value.

Comment: So with databinding you cant use for example `10dp`, instead you should set it in dimen.xml then reference to that?

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful please don't forget to mark it as the right one ;)

Comment: For me it says it cannot find setter for attribute type margin_top with attribute type float.